# Update after fuzzy lookup SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have this question for you.I am working on this package.I am using fuzzy look up.  I have a condition to separate the matching and non matching based on confidentiality and similarity and the **non matching ones I want to update the reference table**.I can't use exec sql task..is there any other way to do this using ssis?Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the [OLEDB Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141138.aspx) transformation component. It will run a SQL command for each row that flows through it.

Take your Lookup No Match Output, map it to an OLEDB Command that does your reference table update given the lookup output's value.

Set the OLEDB Command's SQLCommand to  "UPDATE ReferenceTable set NoMatch=1 Where Value = ?" or whatever query you want to run for no matches ... you get the idea.